# Removing the time on Field object in Crystal Report using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

In my Database i use mysql i have a value of 7/25/2015

My report code:

```
rptmain.Subreports("CrystalReport1.rpt").SetDataSource(dtincom)
```

the problem when i am displaying the report it looks like this

> 7/25/2015 12:00:00 AM

which is not what i want. i want the original value inside my database is this possible without doing such code? please take a look of the picture below.[image]
[image]

Comment: In database is it a date field or datetime field

Comment: sorry but its a DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ToText({DataTable1.date_conduct}, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: i not actually sure why ToText work while CStr doesn't on this. i am converting a date to string and remove the time so in the ToText you can format the string. but i'm not quite sure, this is how i understand it. if you could enlighten me that would be great.